# I'm not able to export the result of my code in an excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, beautifulsoup

Trying to do a webscrapping using Selenium and BeautifulSoup in Python, I came across an error. The print returns what I want, but to save to a CSV file with the pandas DataFrame, I'm not getting it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import json
from time import sleep 




options = Options()
options.headless = True

navegador = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)

link = '**************************'
navegador.get(url = link)
sleep(1)

usuario = navegador.find_element(by=By.ID, value='ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_txtLogin')
usuario.send_keys('**************************')
sleep(1)

senha = navegador.find_element(by=By.ID, value='ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_txtSenha')
senha.send_keys('**************************')
sleep(2.5)

botaologin = navegador.find_element(by=By.ID, value='ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_btnEnviar')
botaologin.click()
sleep(2.5)

agendamento = navegador.find_element(by=By.ID, value='ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_TreeView2t8')
agendamento.click()
sleep(1)

selecdia = navegador.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value='23')
selecdia.click()
sleep(1)


selecterminal = navegador.find_element(by=By.ID, value='ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_ddlVagasTerminalEmpresa')
selecterminal.click()
sleep(1)

select = Select(navegador.find_element(by=By.ID, value='ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_ddlVagasTerminalEmpresa'))
select.select_by_index(1)
sleep(2)

buscalink = navegador.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="divScroll"]')

for element in buscalink:
    teste3 = element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

soup = BeautifulSoup(teste3, "html.parser")


for tag in soup.find_all(title="Vaga disponível."):
    on_click = tag.get('onclick')
    if on_click:
        print(on_click)

df = pd.DataFrame(on_click)
df.to_csv('TESTE.csv')
```

**ERRO :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\entra\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Py\ECOPATIO\ECOPATIOFUNC.py", line 65, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(on_click)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 779, in __init__
    raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

**Expected the following lines in a CSV file,**

*`javascript:window.open('Cadastro.aspx?id_agenda=0&id_turno=23/11/2022 19:00:00;23/11/2022 20:00:00&data=23/11/2022&id_turno_exportador=198194&id_turno_agenda=61186&id_transportadora=23213&id_turno_transp=68048&id_Cliente=40300&codigo_terminal=40300&codigo_empresa=1&codigo_exportador=24978&codigo_transportador=23213&codigo_turno=20&turno_transp_vg=68048','_blank','height=850,width=1000,top=(screen.width)?(screen.width-1000)/2 : 0,left=(screen.height)?(screen.height-700)/2 :
0,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no');

javascript:window.open('Cadastro.aspx?id_agenda=0&id_turno=23/11/2022 23:00:00;24/11/2022 0:00:00&data=23/11/2022&id_turno_exportador=198194&id_turno_agenda=61186&id_transportadora=23213&id_turno_transp=68048&id_Cliente=40300&codigo_terminal=40300&codigo_empresa=1&codigo_exportador=24978&codigo_transportador=23213&codigo_turno=24&turno_transp_vg=68048','_blank','height=850,width=1000,top=(screen.width)?(screen.width-1000)/2 : 0,left=(screen.height)?(screen.height-700)/2 : 0,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no');`*

Comment: That's not a CSV file, and you should not be using pandas at all.  You have grabbed the "onclick" handler for that tag, which is a Javascript function.  What were you expecting to do with this?  Were you hoping to grab the contents of the URL that it would have gone to, had you clicked it?  Since you're using Selenium, why don't you just click that link, and then read the new contents?

Comment: The code enters the link, logs in, clicks on some buttons and extracts the html from the last link, taking the "onclick" tags that are the texts that are returning to me. Which are correct. But it doesn't save to a CSV file. I apologize for my English and for not understanding much about pandas.

Comment: (1) what is the output of `type(on_click)` (2) what is the output of `print(on_click)`?

Comment: javascript:window.open('Cadastro.aspx?id_agenda=0&id_turno=23/11/2022 19:00:00;23/11/2022 20:00:00&data=23/11/2022&id_turno_exportador=198194&id_turno_agenda=61186&id_transport&transportadora&=23213 =68048&id_Cliente=40300&codigo_terminal=40300&codigo_empresa=1&codigo_exportador=24978&codigo_transportador=23213&codigo_turno=20&turno_transp_vg=68048','_blank','height=850,width=1000,top=(screen.width)? ,left=(screen.height)?(screen.height-700)/2 : 0,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no') ;

Comment: output of print(on_click)

Comment: Right, but why?  Why are you fetching `on_click`?  As we have said, the `on_click` attribute is a Javascript function.  I suspect what you WANT to do is click on anything called "Vaga disponivel", but that's not what you do.  You just fetch the body of the function that would be executed if you clicked.

Comment: Your on_click data needs to be an iterable. e.g. a list or something, otherwise it will return that error. E.g. if you want all that onclick data in one column (I presume you don't) `df = pd.DataFrame([on_click])` . But I suspect you want to split your on click data by the commas? So you may need to split it. e.g. `on_click.split(',')` . Then you can call it as a list of lists. e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame([on_click.split(',')])`

Comment: Yes, I want the onclick data in a column, I will try. and I'll talk to you again

Comment: It worked, but it returned only one line, and there are several that return me in print. Another thing. How to make it return only the following content on each line: `Cadastro.aspx?schedule_id=0&shift_id=23/11/2022 19:00:00;23/11/2022 20:00:00&data=23/11/2022&shift_exporter_id=198194&scheduled_shift_id=61186&transport_id&23411/2022&shift_exporter_id=198194&scheduled_shift_id=61186&transport_id&234customer_id=23customer_carrier&24customer_id=23 26_carrier&=26_60:00:00:00; =40300&terminal_code=40300&company_code=1&exporter_code=24978&transporter_code=23213&shift_code=20&shift_transp_vg=68048` .

Comment: The only thing I need is for this code to return the content contained within all the onclicks contained within this HTML, if there is an easier way. The question of "Vaga Disponível ". It was the only easiest way I found to return the available vacancies, discarding the scheduled vacancies.

Comment: someone to help me?